# travis tests fail due to permission denied on .sh file in docker

Tags: bash, docker, flask, travis-ci

I am trying to get travis to work with my containerized flask app. Everything works fine locally build and commit I fail on this command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build -d
```

and here is my error from travis:

```
Successfully built e5cc5b91a3ee
Successfully tagged testdriven-app_nginx:latest
Creating testdriven-app_users-db_1 ... 
ERROR: for testdriven-app_users_1  Cannot start service users: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"
ERROR: for users  Cannot start service users: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
The command "sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

here is my travis yml file and i get that I am failing on the before script section:

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

env:
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.21.1

before_install:
  - sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin

before_script:
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build -d

script:
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml run users python manage.py test
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml run users python flake8 project

after_script:
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down
```

I gave myself chmod on docker compose and from my understanding this should have given me permissions to the file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` have execute (`+x`) permission?

Comment: how would one check that?

Comment: Running `ls -l entrypoint.sh` on the file would be a good start.

Comment: is running that command different between linux and windows? I am a windows enviroment so here is my output                                           Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/5/2018  10:27 PM            158 entrypoint.sh

Comment: `ls` is a Unix command.  I can't help you with Windows.

Comment: @jwodder in case you were curious as to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the dockerprofile from

```
CMD["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

to

```
RUN ["chmod","+x","/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

which fixed the problem